# The average values of a harmonic function over the ball and surface of the ball are the same?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-functions

This is the proof I saw in my text.

[image]
[image]

I can understand all the algebraic manipulations in the proof. But, what I am not sure about is the deriative of the function Φ(r). As far as I know, the average value of a function u(x) over the surface of a ball is $\frac1{s(r)}\int_{∂ ball}u(x) ds$, where s(r) is the surface area of the ball that depends on r. In the text, I saw differentiation with respect to r. Now,here comes my question. If we differentiate with respect to r, with the function $\frac1{s(r)}$ standing outside of the integral, shouldn't we use the product rule? In the text, I only saw the intgral get differentiated as if the average value is obtained by dividing by a constant and not a function of r.

Comment: Note the change of variables that is made near the end of the first image you posted (by the way, you really should make an effort to type up those arguments using MathJax---it would make it easier to understand your question).  $\phi(r)$ can, via this change of variables, be defined as an integral over the unit ball.  Since the unit ball has volume 1, the volume term from the average integral doesn't get in the way.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you. I will try to type up evrything next time I post any question.

Answer (score 1):

This derivative is calculated by first changing variables; intuitively, it's weird to differentiate an integral with respect to $r$, when the integral is over a region that depends on $r$. The change of variables in the first picture does this. It takes the $r$ out of the limits of the integral,  so now we can just pull the derivative inside. This is also why  we don't need the product rule; changing variables as such makes the fraction in front of the integral a constant (the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit sphere). To make this rigorous can be done using $n$-dimensional "polar" coordinates.